# Image not included in vite build

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am trying to have an image in my project but when I build the project the image is not included in the build. Does someone know why? I am using sveltekit and vite. Here is the github: https://github.com/CloudyWhale/personal-website. The name of the photo is trashCan.svg and it is in the static folder.

Here is the build log:

```
> tailwind-svelte@0.0.1 build
> vite build
 
vite v2.9.13 building for production...
✓ 14 modules transformed.
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/manifest.json                            1.21 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/layout.svelte-85bee214.js                0.53 KiB / gzip: 0.35 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/error.svelte-b3f7066d.js                 1.56 KiB / gzip: 0.75 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/pages/index.svelte-46e2bffd.js           3.68 KiB / gzip: 1.80 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/start-5d947e25.js                        22.66 KiB / gzip: 8.58 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/pages/index.svelte-74cec484.css   6.91 KiB / gzip: 1.84 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/index-7fb2b6d1.js                 7.15 KiB / gzip: 2.91 KiB
vite v2.9.13 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 12 modules transformed.
Generated an empty chunk: "hooks"
.svelte-kit/output/server/manifest.json                        1.17 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js                             74.35 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/fallbacks/layout.svelte.js   0.24 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/fallbacks/error.svelte.js    0.72 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/index.svelte.js        14.22 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index-5f038599.js             2.31 KiB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/hooks-1c45ba0b.js             0.00 KiB
 
Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.
(node:89537) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Edit: I forgot to mention this earlier but I am also having this issue when I am building it on my own device

Comment: Questions should be self contained, you should reduce the issue to a minimal example and include all relevant code in the question. Learn about Markdown to format things correctly, nothing weird about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How files are built/output depends on the [adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters). With `@sveltejs/adapter-node`, for example, the assets from `public` will be copied to the `client` sub-directory of the output.

If your adapter does not handle the `public` directory as expected, consider moving your assets to the "official" SvelteKit asset directory, which is `static`.

Comment: I tried moving the file to the static folder but it did not fix the issue. I also made sure to add the static folder to the vite allow list.

Comment: The cloudflare adapter puts all files from `static` into `.svelte-kit/cloudflare`, where did you look?

Comment: I looked in the static folder but thanks for the reply! that fixed the problem